# Filtering in one input multiple values with remove option as x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, filtering

I serched on internet and either i dont know what to look for exactly or there is no support for this type.

I need to implement the following input for my filtering in html with js and jquery. 
This works exactly like stackoverflows Tags input. After space add x at the end.

Anyone have any ideea how? Can someone supply me with some samples?

Sorry now i realized that i didint expressed myself well enough.
I dont need autocomplete, just to add multiple tags with the remove option as x separated only by space

Comment: What you're looking for is called an `autocomplete` control. jQueryUI contains one, although would need amwnding to work with tags. If you google for that 'autocomplete tags' there are several other 3rd party plugins which will do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='selectedElements'></div>
<input type='text' id='useToSelect' value='' onkeyup="testForSpace();">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function testForSpace()
{
    text=$('#useToSelect').val();
    if (text[text.length-1] == ' ') {
        if (text == '') {
            $("#useToSelect").val("");   
        }
    currentSelected=$(".selectedElements").html();
    newSelected="<div class='singleSelectedContainer' onclick='destroyElement(this)' style='float:left;'><div class='singleSelected'><div class='Content'>" + text + "</div><div class='Close'> &nbsp;  x </div><div clear:left;></div></div><div style='float:left; width:7px;'>&nbsp;</div></div>";
    $(".selectedElements").html(currentSelected + newSelected);
    $("#useToSelect").val("");
    }
 }


function destroyElement(elem) {
    $(elem).html('');   
}
```

After you type something in the input field, and press space, it generates a div containing your text, and puts it to the left of the input. If this is what you are looking for, and need more explanation, I will gladly explain to you how this works.

```
function retrieveData() 
{ 
  dataArray=new Array(); 
  $(".singleSelected").each(function() {
    dataArray.push($(this .Content).html());
  });
  return dataArray; //this contains the selected elements 
}
```

Comment: basically something like this. Thanks!  Any ideea how can i format it to look a bit smoother?

Comment: also. Can the fields be saved inside the input?  not as divs

Comment: Basically you have to apply css to .singleSelected . Try giving the borders some radius, and a light grey background to the div, with black font color. Also you can format the closing X and the content separatly (".singleSelected .Content", ".singleSelected .Close"). As for storing the selected data in the input and not in a div, I dunno. As far as I know, you can't style the input content separatly. If you don't know how to retrieve the selected data, later from the div, I can help you with that. Look for the retrieveData function in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get an working example just the way i want. have a nice day.